# I can't get my previous levels and achievements in geometry dash

Tags: geometry-dash

After I uninstalled the game and reinstalled it I had to restart when I logged in  until I found the sync button but that doesn't work because it says this:"sync failed try again  later" so I tried the google play button it shuts down gd. What is happening!?

Answer (score 1):

Before you uninstalled the game, were you in an account? And did you press SAVE in the account before uninstalling?

It could also just be bad Internet or a short error. Try restarting the game too. Hopefully it will load!